# MySQL java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when editing object values and using save() in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a simple Java Spring Boot application and want to change the 'rank' of different objects. The database is fully functioning and I can read from it with no problem. However, when using Spring Data JPA and using the save() function with an object, but only when I change a field of the object, I get a java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException.

I have tried restarting the tomcat server, remaking the database, using different field names, retrieving the object's id and recreating the object only with a different field value, and general random edits.

Animal.java

```
package com.derek.awwmash.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="animal")
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="rank")
    private int rank;

    @Column(name="image")
    private String image;

    public Animal() { }

    public Animal(int id, int rank, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [id=" + id + ", rank=" + rank + ", image=" + image + "]";
    }


}
```

AnimalController.java

```
package com.derek.awwmash.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.derek.awwmash.entity.Animal;
import com.derek.awwmash.service.AnimalService;

@Controller
public class AnimalController {

    private AnimalService animalService;

    @Autowired
    public AnimalController(AnimalService animalService) {
        this.animalService = animalService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        Random r = new Random();

        List<Animal> animals = animalService.findAll();
        int size = animals.size();

        Animal a = animalService.findById(r.nextInt(size) + 1);

        model.addAttribute("animal", a);
        return "home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String selected(@ModelAttribute("animal") Animal animal) {
        System.out.println(animal.toString());

        animal.setRank(999);
        animalService.save(animal);

        System.out.println(animal.toString());
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

AnimalService.java

```
package com.derek.awwmash.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.derek.awwmash.entity.Animal;

public interface AnimalService {
    public List<Animal> findAll();
    public Animal findById(int id);
    public void save(Animal animal);
    public void deleteById(int id);
}
```

AnimalServiceImpl.java

```
package com.derek.awwmash.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.derek.awwmash.dao.AnimalRepository;
import com.derek.awwmash.entity.Animal;

@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AnimalServiceImpl(AnimalRepository animalRepository) {
        this.animalRepository = animalRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Animal> findAll() {
        return animalRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Animal findById(int id) {
        Optional<Animal> result = animalRepository.findById(id);

        Animal animal = null;

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            animal = result.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No animal found with that id: " + id);
        }
        return animal;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Animal animal) {
        animalRepository.save(animal);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        animalRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

AnimalRepository.java

```
package com.derek.awwmash.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.derek.awwmash.entity.Animal;

public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Integer> {

}
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>title</title>
</head>   
    <body>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <br><br>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${animal}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${animal.id}" />
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${animal.rank}" />
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${animal.image}" />
            <input type="image" th:src="@{'images/' + ${animal.image}}" />
        </form>
        <p th:text="'animal object id: '+ ${animal.id}" />
        <p th:text="'animal rank: '+ ${animal.rank}" />
        <p th:text="'animal image name: '+ ${animal.image}" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Script I used to create the MySQL table

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `aww_directory`;
USE `aww_directory`;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `animal`;

CREATE TABLE `animal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `image` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `animal` VALUES 
    (1, 50, 'test1.jpg'),
    (2, 47, 'test2.jpg');
```

When clicking on the image in the home.html file, it should be setting the object's 'rank' field to '999' by use of the Spring Data JPA 'save(obj)' function however I get a SQLSyntaxError:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank=999 where id=1' at line 1
```

My full stack trace upon clicking the image is:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Aug 03 15:54:17 EDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.derek.awwmash.service.AnimalServiceImpl.save(AnimalServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.derek.awwmash.controller.AnimalController.selected(AnimalController.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3360)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3233)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3634)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank=999 where id=1' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 90 more
```

Comment: Try logging the SQL statement (add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to your properties file) to see if that brings any clarity. Also, could you share the table definition?

Comment: Could you share the dialect that you are using?

Comment: You may use a different column name as it seems "rank" it is reserved word.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: @KellyM Updated post for table creation - unfortunately the logging did not show anything different

Comment: @m.hassaballah Oh wow yes that was the issue. Reserved words skipped my mind. Thank you very much I will bookmark that for now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this issue is due you are using Mysql reserved words since 8.0.2 version like is `rank`field.

You can take a look [SQL reserved words for Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) and you have two options

1. Rename `rank` column to `rank_img` or column name that you want.

   ```
   @Column(name = "rank_img")
   private int rank;
   ```
2. Force to use `rank` column name.

   If you are using JPA, you can escape with double quotes:

   ```
   @Column(name = "\"rank\"")
   private int rank;
   ```

   If you're using Hibernate native API, then you can escape them using backticks:

   ```
   @Column(name = "`rank`")
   private int rank;
   ```

Comment: I faced this problem because the name of my table name (match) is a reserved keyword in mysql. I changed table name to football_match and it solved the issue.